# Why my freeMem function expects char* and addMem funcion char**

Tags: c, malloc

Maybe the title is horrible, but I will try to explain may problem.

Lets take a look at the following program:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void addMem1 ( char **arr, size_t size );
void freeMem ( char *ptr );

int main ( void )
{
    size_t size = 256;
    char *arr;

    addMem1( &arr, size );
    strcpy( arr, "Hello there!" );

    printf( "Arr = %s\n", arr );
    freeMem( arr ); ///I do not need a pointer to Pointer here

}

void addMem1 ( char **arr, size_t size  )
{
    *arr = calloc ( size * sizeof( **arr ), sizeof( **arr ) );
    if ( *arr == NULL )
    {
        printf("Error, malloc()\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}

void freeMem ( char *ptr )
{
    if ( ptr != NULL )
    {
        free( ptr );
    }
}
```

When I pass `arr` to `addMem()` to make it work I need to pass it like this `&arr` because I cannot use `malloc` in `addMem()`.

Here is another version of `freeMem()`:

```
void freeMem ( char **ptr )
{
    if ( *ptr != NULL )
    {
        free( *ptr );
    }
}
```

When I call it, works fine with:

```
freeMem( &arr );
```

And it is wrong like this:

```
freeMem( arr );
```

How does exactly works `free()` function?

Why the function

`void freeMem ( char *ptr );`

works only by using a single Pointer?
And I do not need to define it like this:

`void freeMem ( char **ptr );`

**EDIT:**

To be more precise, I do not understand why This function is wrong, when is used on the pointer `arr`:

```
void addMem1 ( char *arr, size_t size  ) /// is wrong, need to pass by Reference
{
    arr = calloc ( size * sizeof( *arr ), sizeof( *arr ) );
    if ( arr == NULL )
    {
        printf("Error, malloc()\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}
```

But it does work this one:

```
void freeMem1 ( char *ptr ) /// here is by Value?
{
    if ( ptr != NULL )
    {
        free( ptr );
    }
}
```

In the last function I do not need reference?

Comment: @alk Sorry about that. I correct it.

Comment: I do not understand this "*because I cannot use `malloc` in `addMem()`.*" You *do* use `calloc()`, which is the sister function to `malloc()`.

Comment: You need to google "pass by value" and "pass by reference" and learn the difference between them and when each one is used.

Comment: @n.m. [Please check this. I explain it better in the comments](https://pastebin.com/raw/wgkCdAJg). Maybe you will understand, what I do not undestand.

Comment: I believe I understood your problem the first time around. I believe you don't understand why we pass variables by reference, when we need to do so, and when we don't. I believe this is exactly the piece of knowledge you are missing. I have programmed C professionally for a quarter of a century and during this time I have seen a lot of people making the exact same mistakes. This gives me some confidence in making these assertions, though of course I can still be wrong.

Comment: @n.m. In the main program (The first one) does `arr` being passed as value or as reference here ==>> `freeMem( arr );` ?

Comment: C has no references per se. It uses the `&` operator to simulate pass by reference. "Pass by reference" is a rigid fixed phrase, don't try to use slightly different words, "as reference" doesn't work. So if you see the `&` operator in a function call, the variable is being passed by reference. If not, it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does exactly works `free()` function?

[`free()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.3) deallocates the memory the value passed points to, addresses.

`free()` expects values returned by `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()` (or `NULL`, where is in fact does nothing).

Comment: Yes, I do know that. I can not understand, why there is no need for a pointer to pointer in `freeMem()`. For `malloc` I need a pointer to pointer. For `free` works both, `char*` and `char**`. Why?

Comment: Look at this and rethink: This `*&v == v` holds true for each variable, including pointers

Comment: @MichaelB.: Also think about what the `*` is doing here: `*arr = calloc ( ...`

Comment: So, `free()` expects just the value of the pointer and `calloc` expects the Pointer? The way the program is designed I pass here `freeMem( arr)` as a variable and not via pointer.

Comment: [Please check this.](https://pastebin.com/raw/wgkCdAJg).  I explain it better in the comments